# SQL Query works in phpmyAdmin but not on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a sort of double query that works perfect in phpMyAdmin (trying to get data out of a Wordpress created database) but cannot get it to work on a standalone php page that is not loading any wordpress functions. In the second query `193` is from `$_POST['MAINID']`.

Here's the first query that works in phpMyAdmin but not in PHP:

```
Select distinct wpum.user_id, sum(wppm2.meta_value)
from wp_usermeta wpum
inner join wp_postmeta wppm1 on wpum.user_id = wppm1.meta_value and wppm1.meta_key = 'school_id'
inner join wp_postmeta wppm2 on wppm1.post_id = wppm2.post_id and wppm2.meta_key = 'total_price'    
where Umeta_ID in (select MIN(umeta_id) from wp_usermeta group by USER_ID)    
group by wpum.user_id
```

Then here is the second query to make sense of the results but does not work in PHP:

```
select SUM(meta_value) from wp_postmeta
where post_id
in (select distinct post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_value = '193')
and meta_key = 'total_price'
```

It returns 331 rows at it should. But I can't get anything to work on the page. I've tried `mysqli_multi_query`, `MYSQL_ASSOC`, and even simple result dumps with no formatting. I just want to display a total sales amount for user `193`.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); //define sql query
$sql = "Select distinct wpum.user_id, sum(wppm2.meta_value) from wp_usermeta wpum inner join wp_postmeta wppm1 on wpum.user_id = wppm1.meta_value and wppm1.meta_key = 'school_id' inner join wp_postmeta wppm2 on wppm1.post_id = wppm2.post_id and wppm2.meta_key = 'total_price' where Umeta_ID in (select MIN(umeta_id) from wp_usermeta group by USER_ID) group by wpum.user_id";
```

PHP version is 5.2 and MySQL version is 5.5.42.

Comment: Does PDO throw any error (`print_r($dbh->errorInfo()`) or just return an empty result?

Comment: It gives me this: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: The second index is empty? If it does, then it seems PDO doesn't encounter any syntax error, it just return an empty result. One possible reason that the same query works in PhpMyAdmin but not in PHP could be that there is some encoding issue that PhpMyAdmin can handle but PHP can't. What's the charset of the tables you're trying to query? Btw, if you're in Wordpress, could you try to use WPDB instead?